# MySQL Extra condition in JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-conditions

I am creating a news feed for my website with posts from users you are following and I was wondering what would be the correct syntax to add an extra condition to my SQL statement, to show your own posts in this feed also, everything I have tried has resulted in an error, here is my current query:

```
     SELECT posts.*
       FROM posts 
 INNER JOIN follow 
         ON posts.uid = follow.following_id 
      WHERE follow.follower_id = '$myUser' 
   ORDER BY posts.id DESC 
      LIMIT 10
```

So, how would I add a condition to also show posts with the uid of $myUser variable?

**EDIT:**

Table structure:

posts:

```
id | uid | message | date_posted
```

follow:

```
id | follower_id | following_id
```

Comment: Any chance you can share the result set of your current query, it may help to see how we can expand on it.

Comment: I don't see how that's necessary? All's I need is to add another exception to return posts with the user's own ID as well as people they are following.

Comment: Perhaps not, I was just curious. I shared one answer, did you try an OR statement in the where clause?

Comment: Both OR + AND still only return posts of people I am following, rather than showing my own also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT      posts.* 

FROM        posts 
INNER JOIN  follow ON posts.uid = follow.following_id 

WHERE       follow.follower_id = '$myUser' 
            OR 
            posts.uid = '$myUser' 

ORDER BY    posts.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I updated my comment, just realized OR would make more sense, going to try it out in a few mins and I can't accept it yet anyway, need to wait 10 minutes.

Comment: It depends on the requirement it may be `and` or `or`

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to say without an overview of your database structure, but a good place to start would be to change the join to a LEFT join, and adding in a condition to check your own ID which I assume in the posts table. So, maybe:

`SELECT posts.* FROM posts LEFT JOIN follow ON posts.uid = follow.following_id WHERE (follow.follower_id = '$myUser' OR posts.user_id = '$myUser') ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 10`

That may be somewhere to start.

Comment: No difference using this, still only shows the posts of people I am following, not my own.

Comment: Like I say, we would really need some sort of database structure. The second part of the query will just need to check wherever you store the ID of who created the post.

Comment: I'll update my question with the structure, I assumed it would be understandable from the query.

Comment: Did you definitely change the join to a Left join too? It basically needs to check if either the uid of the post is yours, or the follower_id is yours, which is what this would do. However, it needs to be a left join because your posts won't have a match in the followers table.

Comment: Yeah, exactly the same as your query and still only shows the followed user posts.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use the OR clause for this, so you will receive any posts from the follower OR the user. If you used AND, it would return a post with an id of the follower AND the user, which may return nothing.

So this:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts INNER JOIN follow ON posts.uid = follow.following_id WHERE follow.follower_id = '$myUser' ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Would become:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts INNER JOIN follow ON posts.uid = follow.following_id WHERE follow.follower_id = '$myUser' OR posts.uid = '$myUser' ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Unfortunately, I can't test this right now, but I hope that if it doesn't work it at least helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference, thanks for the reply however.

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to figure this one out. Let me know if you ever get the solution to it, but I'll keep it in the back of my head.